# Having an issue with assets, while i am upload the image from the admin

Tags: assets

When i have upload the image using below settings that will give me an error  The error message was: **"Error uploading the file: The file system path "/public_html/src/assets/images/" set for this source does not exist.**

general.php file

```
<?php

 $siteUrl = array(
    'en_gb' => 'https://www.ancamotion.com/',
    'de' => 'https://www.ancamotion.de/',
    'zh_cn' => 'https://www.ancamotion.cn/',
    'zh_tw' => 'https://www.ancamotion.com.tw/',
);

return array(

    '*' => array(
        'devMode' => false,
        'extraAllowedFileExtensions' => 'exe, xml',
        'maxUploadFileSize' => 67108864,
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'timezone' => 'Australia/Melbourne',
        'setPasswordPath' => array(
            'en' => 'securezone/resetpasswordform.html',
                 'de' => 'securezone/resetpasswordform.html',
                  'cn' => 'securezone/resetpasswordform.html',
        ),
        'setPasswordSuccessPath' => array(
            'en' => 'password/thanks-reset.html',
                'de' => 'password/thanks-reset.html',
                'cn' => 'password/thanks-reset.html',
        ),
    ),

   'ancamotion.com' => array(
        'siteUrl' => $siteUrl,
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'basePath' => '/public_html/',
            'baseUrl'  => 'https://www.ancamotion.com/',
        ),
    ),
   'ancamotion.de' => array(
        'siteUrl' => $siteUrl,
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'basePath' => '/public_de/',
            'baseUrl'  => 'https://www.ancamotion.de/',
        ),
    ),
   'ancamotion.cn' => array(
        'siteUrl' => $siteUrl,
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'basePath' => '/public_cn/',
            'baseUrl'  => 'https://www.ancamotion.cn/',
        ),
    ),
   'ancamotion.com.tw' => array(
        'siteUrl' => $siteUrl,
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'basePath' => '/public_tw/',
            'baseUrl'  => 'https://www.ancamotion.com.tw/',
        ),
    ),

);
```

my settings from website admin Assets are

File System Path --> {basePath}src/assets/images/

URL --> {baseUrl}src/assets/images/

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank You in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

That error message means your `basePath` is incorrect and Craft can't find the directory you're referring to.

From your settings, it looks like Craft would try to upload images to `/public_html/src/assets/images/`. If that's correct, try using `/` or nothing instead of your current `basePath`. And make sure the folder exists on the server.

Comment: thanks, and i have tried this in my general.php but didnt work, but i can see my base url is right like, for english website -- https://www.ancamotion.com/src/assets/images/(imagename), for my german website https://www.ancamotion.de/src/assets/images/(imagename), but here image is not appear is because basepath is wrong and didnt upload the image in --> public_de/src/assets/images/. same thing happen with other two domains as well only english is working fine, any more thought? thank you in advance. addy